# clashing libraries after importing play-services

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting clashes in libraries after importing the dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
```

This is the line where the error is reported at this line:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

This is the error:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes).

Found version 26.1.0, 25.2.0
```

If I change the line

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
```

Now I get

```
This support library should not use a different version (25) than the compile SDK version (26).
```

What is happening. It's a like a circular error of some kind.

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere else (perhaps in a dependency), you are compiling another portion of the Android support library with version 25.2.0.  If you want to use compile SDK version 26 then you'll need to update all references to com.android.support to version 26.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes).
>
> Found version 26.1.0, 25.2.0

This is because you have two support library which is `26.1.0` and `25.2.0`. There is one or more library that use a different version of support library. So, you need to find it and use the exclude in the dependency. You can found them by looking at the dependency tree by executing the following command in your project in Linux shell (use gradlew.bat if you using Windows):

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

After you've found it, exclude the support library from it with:

```
compile(com.sample.library) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'

    // exclude the support library that is clashing.
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Then, you need to add the support library to replace the excluded version in the previous dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```